# Embedding logo image in Telerik Kendo Grid Excel Export

Tags: kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I'm use Telerik Kendo Grids in my current project and currently we are evaluating it as a good alternative for our server side excel export. I'm using the latest Kendo library and one of the place I got struck up is how we can embed a logo image at the header of the excel file? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this feature is [yet to be implemented](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-with-image-export-in-excel). You can vote it up so it gets implemented [here](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/11603982-excel-export-with-image-for-grid).